# Circular clip path for two mapbox gl natives?

Tags: react-native, opengl-es, mapbox-gl, clip-path, react-native-maps

Is it possible to display two native mapboxes in such a way, that one is an inner circle within the other, and all move/zoom events propagate to both?

For the JS version I could use: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-compare/

and then set the clip-path like so:

```
   this.map1.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].style['clip-path'] = 'circle(' + pixelDistance + 'px at center)';

   this.map1.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].style['position'] = 'initial';
```

Giving something like this:
[image]

Now, say I was going to use React Native like so:

```
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <MapView
      ref={map => { this._map = map }}
      style={styles.map}
      initialZoomLevel={this.state.zoom}
      initialCenterCoordinate={this.state.center}
      initialDirection={0}
      rotateEnabled={true}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      styleURL={Config.MAPBOX_MAP_1}
      zIndex={2}
    />
    <MapView
      ref={map => { this._map = map }}
      style={styles.map}
      initialZoomLevel={this.state.zoom}
      initialCenterCoordinate={this.state.center}
      initialDirection={0}
      rotateEnabled={true}
      scrollEnabled={true}
      zoomEnabled={true}
      styleURL={Config.MAPBOX_MAP_2}
      zIndex={1}
    />
</View>)
```

leaning on https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl

How would I reproduce similar behavior?